# Kubuntu problem with removing .deb from disc?

Tags: package-management, deb

I'm a new kubuntu user, I don't know much, so please understand, I installed minetest from discover, but unfortunately not the snap version, and I managed to delete everything in the console except 4 files minetest_5.4.1+repack-2bulid1_amd64.deb I have such files 2, another one is minetest-data_5.4.1+repack-2build1_all.deb and these I also have 2 how to delete them I want to learn to always keep my disk in order

Comment: Please edit your question and add information how you deleted the files. If you installed something via the packet management system (which Discover does), use the package management system to uninstall. Never deleted anything manually, this may leave the system worst case in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives/
sudo rm minetest-data_5.4.1+repack-2build1_all.deb
```

---

From command line: change directory to where those files are. As an example `cd ~/Downloads` if in your home's Download directory. Then do

```
rm -i mimetest
```

and hit TAB for it to complete the name as much as it can. Add a '*' and enter. That will remove the files while asking for confirmation for each file. Drop the `-i` if you just want to delete those files.

From the desktop: open the file explorer, got to the directory, select the files and hit 'del'. Files are then 'moved' to the Trash.

Comment: I do not quite know what you wrote, as I say I am a total layman these 2 files I have in such a place  /var/cache/apt/archives/minetest-data_5.4.1+repack-2build1_all.deb

Comment: ah see the 1st 2 lines I added. replace the file for the other ones your need removing. you can also add a "*"  and do `mimetest*` to delete all starting with mimetest.

Comment: Succeeded, thank you very much and sorry for the confusion, I will say that it is all a bit complicated <3

Comment: @AlfredRobaczkiewicz nah, it i just a matter of a bit of experience. forget how  windows does it; that is a single user system changed to a multi user system.Linux was always mult-user so it is also set up to be used as that even though we desktop users tend to be single users.

Comment: thanks again probably with time I will learn some things greetings !